# Replace symbols with HTML-tags

Tags: regex, perl

I would like to replace symbols with HTMLtags. For example:

```
This :is: some :text: that could also look :a: bit :different:.
```

should become

```
This <span id="selected">is</span> some <span id="selected">text</span> that could also look <span id="selected">a</span> bit <span id="selected">different</span>.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
$str = "This :is: some :text: that could also look :a: bit :different:";
$str =~ s/:(\w+):/<span id='selected'>$1<\/span>/g;
print $str;
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$s =~ s{:([^:]+):}{<span id="selected">$1</span>}g;
```

Answer (score 1):

```
(:)(.+?)\1
```

using `\1` will allow you to change out the ":" to other characters and make sure the closing matches.